# Android Studio: Can you control apps running in background from another app?

Tags: java, android, xml

I am trying to create an Android app that shuts Spotify and thereby turning off music after you fall asleep.

The user gets to choose how long to keep the app running. My question is, can I kill background apps from my current app.

I tried looking on Android Studio's developer website and Google but could not find the answer I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Service runs in your app process. If your app is garbage collected, the service will stop until:

You start the service in new process via manifest file declaration
You make the service sticky (recommended).
go ahead and research above two and let me know if you would like more explanation or code

If you see official documentation of [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html), Google clearly explains why and when service will be destroyed. What is useful in your scenario:

> A started service can use the startForeground(int, Notification) API
>   to put the service in a foreground state, where the system considers
>   it to be something the user is actively aware of and thus not a
>   candidate for killing when low on memory. (It is still theoretically
>   possible for the service to be killed under extreme memory pressure
>   from the current foreground application, but in practice this should
>   not be a concern.)

using startForeground will ensure your service keeps running in the same process. some pointers:

A service with attached client will not be destroyed even on low memory scenarios
A service will be killed in low memory scenarios, regardless of the process. Running in a different process is better but does not guarantee it won't be destroyed by system.
Don't use system.exit(0) to end your app. call finish() on activity.
Starting sticky service just ensures that service is restarted when memory is freed.

hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the information, I will look into it. Appreciate your help :)